# Can we use object custom field in place of custom metadata RecordAPIName in formula field?

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to use custom metadata in formula field

`$CustomMetadata.CustomMetadataTypeAPIName.RecordAPIName.FieldAPIName`

but instead of `RecordAPIName`, I have to use custom field - `Country__c`.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In `RecordAPIName`, you use API name of specific record, and field API name like Country__c in `FieldAPIName`